# null safety error | Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

We are trying to upgrade our flutter project to null safety migration using the following link https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide.

dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety - Successful dart pub get - Successful Migrate your code by hand- https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#migrating-by-hand - Successful dart migrate - Successful

Facing error in the below code while trying to run the flutter command(Flutter run)

```
 static Future<AppStrings> getAppText(String local) async {
    var appTextBox = await Hive.openBox("appTextBox");
    AppStrings appText = new AppStrings(
      mainPageTitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle'),
      timeText: appTextBox.get('timeText'),
      minutesText: appTextBox.get('minutesText'),
      mainPageSubtitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageSubtitle'),
      mainPageParagraph: appTextBox.get('mainPageParagraph'),
      mainPageButton: appTextBox.get('mainPageButton'),
      restartButton: appTextBox.get('restartButton'),
      backButton: appTextBox.get('backButton'),
      profileTitle: appTextBox.get('profileTitle'),
      loadingPageSubtitle: appTextBox.get('loadingPageSubtitle'),
      loadingPageBottomText: appTextBox.get('loadingPageBottomText'),
      loadingPageTitle: appTextBox.get('loadingPageTitle'),
      profileButton: appTextBox.get('profileButton'),
      resultRestart: appTextBox.get('resultRestart'),
      resultTitle: appTextBox.get('resultTitle'),
      resultSwipe: appTextBox.get('resultSwipe'),
      secondaryTitle: appTextBox.get('secondaryTitle'),
      tretiaryProductTitle: appTextBox.get('tertiaryTitle'),
    );
    return appText;
  }
```

Update:-

This is how we are calling this method from main.dart file

```
AppStrings? appText = (await DatabaseUtils.getAppText(local ?? ''));
  return Data(
      allProfiles: allProfiles,...........
)
```

Answer (score 0):

change to
getAppText(String? local)
or
getAppText(String local ?? '')

Comment: we are still facing the same issue. I have updated the description with the function call

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 static Future<AppStrings?> getAppText(String local) async {
   var appTextBox = await Hive.openBox("appTextBox");
   AppStrings? appText = new AppStrings(
     mainPageTitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageTitle'),
     timeText: appTextBox.get('timeText'),
     minutesText: appTextBox.get('minutesText'),
     mainPageSubtitle: appTextBox.get('mainPageSubtitle'),
     mainPageParagraph: appTextBox.get('mainPageParagraph'),
     mainPageButton: appTextBox.get('mainPageButton'),
     restartButton: appTextBox.get('restartButton'),
     backButton: appTextBox.get('backButton'),
     profileTitle: appTextBox.get('profileTitle'),
     loadingPageSubtitle: appTextBox.get('loadingPageSubtitle'),
     loadingPageBottomText: appTextBox.get('loadingPageBottomText'),
     loadingPageTitle: appTextBox.get('loadingPageTitle'),
     profileButton: appTextBox.get('profileButton'),
     resultRestart: appTextBox.get('resultRestart'),
     resultTitle: appTextBox.get('resultTitle'),
     resultSwipe: appTextBox.get('resultSwipe'),
     secondaryTitle: appTextBox.get('secondaryTitle'),
     tretiaryProductTitle: appTextBox.get('tertiaryTitle'),
   );

   return appText;
 }
```

And try leave the call like you showed above.